# Pycord add_roles error ("404 Not Found: Unknown Role", even though the role exists)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

With the following code:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, help_command=None)

class GiveRole(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, member: discord.Member):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.server_roles = bot.get_guild(1114203090950836284).roles
        print(self.server_roles)
        self.member = member


    @discord.ui.button(label="G1", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="1️⃣", row=0) # Error comes from this line

    async def grade1(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await self.member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(self.server_roles, id=1114212978707923167))
```

Every time my bot runs the following code:

```
await self.member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(self.server_roles, id=1114212978707923167))
```

it raises

`discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

despite the role existing.

Comment: Have you enabled privileged intents both in the code and on the developer portal?

Comment: How have you tested that the role exists? Are you sure you copied both the guild ID and role ID correctly? In addition, what intents do you have enabled? Please share your client initialisation code in the question.

Comment: @Raymus Yes, I'm sure that all privileged intents are enabled.

Comment: @amycodes I used  `print(discord.utils.get(self.server_roles, id=1114212978707923167))`, and it shows the correct detail about that role. I got those IDs by right-clicking my server and the role.
Thanks for your suggestion, I've edited my question.

Comment: @AllenWei Does that mean that the discord.utils.get returned the role?

Comment: @AllenWei did the `get_guild` function return the guild properly?

Comment: @BlueRobin Yes, `discord.utils.get` returned the role, and `get_guild` also returned the correct guild.

Comment: @AllenWei Try type(role) and see what it prints out

Comment: @BlueRobin it prints `<class 'discord.role.Role'>`